# jQuery dialog - Use jquery / ajax to edit table data inline

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am in some kind of doubt here, currently I used a jquery modal dialog to display details of a db instance. The dialog load a partial view which display data details in table form. I want to allow user to click on the Edit button, and directly edit data in the table ( to be specific, I want to trigger a change in every  @Html.DisplayFor  into an editable field ). I got no idea how this can be done, do I need to have another dialog after user click on Edit? Any other possible way to do this??

Really appreciate any help...

---

I call my dialog in View like this:

```
        //Call Details action to display the food details
        var url = 'Details?cid=' + id;

        $detaildialog.dialog({ open: function () { $(this).load(url) } });
        $detaildialog.dialog('open');
```

The Details action will return my partial view, which is the table i used to display all my Food instance details (below is part of it):

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FoodName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FoodAmount)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StorageDate)
    </td>
```

Any clue?? Please help..

Comment: can you paste the markup that your view is generating or a part of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dynamically hide show a label / input for editing yourself, but **using a jQuery table that already has this functionality may be easier**:

- Here is an article using [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) with some plugins to achieve inline editing.  I've used DataTables extensively and they get the job done quite well.
  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MVC-CRUD-DataTable.aspx
- [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php) appears to support inline editing as well
  http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html#

Answer (score 0):

the question is vague for me but you can attach a class to every editable field and then attach a change event handler

`class = "editablefield"`

and in jquery

```
$(".editablefield").live("change", function(){

//your code to handle change here

});
```

i have used `live` just in case to handle the dynamically added elements to the `DOM`

[`jquery .live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

[`jquery .change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)